# Get from IJavaProject or IProject to org.apache.maven.model.Model

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am inside the `execute` method of my implementation for `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler`. From `ExecutionEvent` I can get the project reference:

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
{
    TreeSelection selection = (TreeSelection)HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
    IJavaElement je = (IJavaElement)selection.getFirstElement()
    IJavaProject jproj = je.getJavaProject();
    IProject p = (IProject)jproj.getResource();
    //...
}
```

Through core expressions I ensure that the project has java and maven natures. So I want to get a maven model from that project. Of course there is an approach to get it from file:

```
MavenXpp3Reader mReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model pomModel = mReader.read(p.getFile("pom.xml").getContents());
```

But since I have access to the workspace I am not sure if I really need to read the POM file myself. I think it should be already evaluated by the m2eclipse plugin. Is there a way to access the maven model of a project somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out there is a maven project registry which keeps all known maven projects of the workspace. With its aid I can get to the maven model without reading the POM manually:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
{
    TreeSelection selection = (TreeSelection)HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
    IJavaElement je = (IJavaElement)selection.getFirstElement();
    IJavaProject jproj = je.getJavaProject();
    IProject proj = (IProject)jproj.getResource();
    IMavenProjectFacade facade = MavenPlugin.getMavenProjectRegistry().getProject(proj);
    Model mavenModel = facade.getMavenProject().getModel();
    //...
    return null;
}
```

**Edit:** Usage of `IMavenProjectFacade#getMavenProject()` is not null safe. If m2eclipse hasn't loaded a referenced project to its cache yet (i.e. right after eclipse start), it will return null. That's why it's better to use `IMavenProjectFacade#getMavenProject(IProgressMonitor monitor)` which does "lazy load and cache MavenProject instance" according to the [javadocs](https://github.com/achingbrain/m2e-core/blob/master/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/project/IMavenProjectFacade.java#L80).

Comment: The additional benefit of this way is that you get a resolved model, where you get proper values instead of maven properties if some used.